# Are these CSS selector syntax equivalent?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would want to know if both the syntax below are valid and equivalent?

```
    /* Type: 1 */     

    html, body {

    } 

    /* Type: 2 */ 

    html body {

    }
```

Comment: First one means "appy to both `html` and `body` tags" and the second one means "apply to `body` tag which is inside `html` tag"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both valid, but not equivalent.

**Group Selectors**

```
html, body {

}
```

**Descendant selector**

```
html body {

}
```